# Wait for view controllers animations to finish before taking screenshot

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that programmatically will take a screenshot `[self makeScreenshot]`. But sometimes, when a rotation happens for example, the result can be very ugly with black parts in it. So I’m trying to make a method with a completion that will wait for the view controllers animations to finish, so that the screenshots can be made safely and always look nice. The call would maybe look something like this:

```
[self methodWithCompletionWhenAnimationsIsDone:^(BOOL finished) {
        // now it's safe to make the screenshot.
        UIImage *myScreenshot = [self makeScreenshot];
    }];
```

But I cant figure out how the code for such a method would look like. Any suggestions?

I’ve tried to place screenshot code the `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`-method and it didn't work. And I don't want to use any rotation callback methods either, because the problem occurs at other occasions as well.

Comment: Are you talking about rotation animations or your custom animations?

Comment: what kind of animations are you considering ?  Animation is done ?

Comment: Yes, but I have a split view, so other animations, like when master view shows/disappear happens also. I'm talking about all the animations that the view controller handle behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which method for animation you are using, but I will give you an example of the default `UIView` animation with completion:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    /* Some animation here */
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    UIImage *myScreenshot = [self makeScreenshot];
}];
```

Comment: The completion Block runs on the main thread already; if it didn't, you wouldn't be allowed to perform chained animations using it.

Comment: Makes sense. I am going to edit my answer, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you try to perform it in background thread

```
[self methodWithCompletionWhenAnimationsIsDone:^(BOOL finished) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         UIImage *myScreenshot = [self makeScreenshot];
    });
}];
```